# Is it OK to downvote questions for simple mistakes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Recently saw a post that had an issue like this...

```
.....;"
```

When it should have been:

```
......";
```

Now, I'm all for downvoting stupid questions and questions that clearly don't have any effort in them. But issues like this could be taking the person hours to figure out. We've all been there. A stupid spelling mistake or whatever costing you an hour of your time. You just don't see the issue no matter how hard you look.

But my issue is that this question was downvoted to hell and had such angry comments. There has to be a better way of going about these than ruining a score.

Comment: If there were inappropriate comments, flag them. As for downvotes, hard to tell without seeing the post, but there's not much you can do about those.

Comment: 20 downvotes simply means 20 different people found the question to be not useful. The comments may not be appropriate, but there's nothing wrong with the downvotes.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474458/ -- unless they have already been removed, none of the comments look angry

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Trying to find it again. Give me a sec and I'll update you with the link.

Comment: `-1` because you didn't format your code `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake Oh god, I'm so bad at SO =p

Answer (score 23):

You seem to be under the mistaken impression that SO is a site where people come here just to be helped out by the community.  That is not what SO is for.  It is not here just to help one individual who asks a question.  It's here *to create a repository of knowledge beneficial to the entire programming community*.  When one person has a typo in their post that they don't notice it's not creating an artifact that is going to help anyone else.  They will be the only person helped by that question.  That's not what SO is about.

Comment: That's a very good point. I never thought of it that way.

Comment: you know you can edit the typo out rather than burn the knowledge right?

Comment: @gia Editing out the problem that the question is asking about makes the question nonsensical, as it's asking to fix something that isn't broken.  While there is no knowledge in a typo to "burn", you're the one advocating deleting what of the problem is there by editing it out.

Comment: what? ok, so the typo was the problem? alright then, I thought the good question was closed due to a typo, nvm