# Should I downvote/comment/edit/ignore questions with a snarky tone?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

### Related Questions, but Not Duplicate

New poster on Meta. Looked at [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) but didn't see an answer here; there are "Is it OK to downvote questions because of ..." questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253611/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-for-simple-mistakes), but searches for "tone" and "snarky" didn't find anything relevant...

### My Question

Suppose that I see a question that's otherwise reasonable, but contains a snarky comment/has a general tone that I find objectionable. Consider, for example, a question phrased as

- "Why is XX in language Y so horribly slow?" vs.
- "How can I speed up XX in language Y?"

The questions could be *answered* similarly. **Should I downvote? Comment? Hold my nose? Edit?**

Arguments for:

- **Downvoting**: I find neutrally phrased questions most useful, and would like to encourage them/discourage snarky questions.
- **Editing**: this is certainly a direct way to address the problem, and could be constructive (i.e. "here is a better way to phrase this question"). It might lead to more constructive answers (rather than a snark-fest in the comments), and to upvotes for an otherwise useful question.
- **Commenting**: it's a milder way to register my disapproval, and I could give suggested edits in a comment and give the original poster the free choice whether to incorporate them.
- **Ignoring**: life is too short.

Comment: I think comments are nice. And ideally the comment doesn't get too snarky about the original snark.

Comment: I edit those, along with the other mistakes they make. It gets the message across adequately and it immediately gets rid of the negative atmosphere it creates.

Comment: The hypothetical questions you gave in your question are opinion polls and don't belong anyway.

Comment: @GarryVass, fair enough. I could change the latter ('good') version to "how can I speed up the execution of XX in Y under the following conditions"? ... (although IMO some "why is X slow" questions are actually reasonable ones that can be answered precisely/technically).

Comment: Something like that, yes.  I was getting ready to submit an answer defending some expressions of sarcasm and irony, but I'll wait...

Comment: A question that pisses on the tool that every [tag] visitor uses never needs any help getting downvoted :)  Yes, life's too short.

Comment: There's something to be said for snarky ANSWERS, which seem to be rather more common, usually aiming the nastiness at the asker for daring to use a method that the answerer doesn't personally like. Same applies, though, I think...edit if minor, downvote is major, flag if destructively rude.

Comment: I'm not wild about all of the latest round of edits (esp. the headings), but the editor is much more experienced on Meta, so I can live with it ...

Comment: Always consider the goal of creating a database of good question and answers. When editing contributes, then do it.

Comment: I'd personally edit the question in question -- pun not intended. Unfortunately I now have to add classifying snarky questions and/or questions that are likely to provoke snarky comments to my little pet projects to-do-list... https://github.com/Niellles/snark-by-the-hour

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If the question itself is not something we'd otherwise close, I would first opt for editing to remove the snark.

However, I find extreme cases of that kind of tone correlates pretty highly with questions that are primarily opinion based or off topic.

If the question itself is not worth keeping, even without the snark, I'd just down vote and/or vote to close (if applicable) and move on.

I have almost never found commenting in those situations to lead to anything remotely resembling a constructive dialog, and so I'd rarely recommend commenting.

As an advocate for being a good SO "housekeeper" I'd argue against ignoring it completely. Better to do what you can to improve the question, particularly if (like myself) you resolve to not engage in the comments.

Answer (score -3):

Downvoting is to a large degree up to you. Unless the questions is really snarky, I would not even consider it. Your example is one of them where I would not even react, but I want to emphasize that it could be because it's taken out of context. I would NOT rephrase it the way you suggested though. Because it DOES change the question. Granted, they would probably lead to somewhat similar answers, but it's not guaranteed. *"Why is XX in language Y so horribly slow?"* is about the reason for it being slow, which may be a very interesting and enlightening subject. *"How can I speed up XX in language Y?"* is instead focused on the solutions. Maybe you could switch "horribly" to "extremely" or just remove the word, but apart from that I think it would have been a bad edit and I would reject it.

**Important difference between snarky in a question compared to comments**

When writing questions, you are in general not snarky against someone, which you usually are in comments. That thing alone makes me think of this as a problem that you only find when you have found and dealt with all other problems and really cannot stand not having a problem to deal with. Maybe I have a bit of a thicker skin, but I have NEVER encountered a question with problems with snarky formulations. Mostly when they are negative about something, it has nothing to do with anyone who reads the question.

> Downvoting: I find neutrally phrased questions most useful, and would like to encourage them/discourage snarky questions.

Downvoting feels quite rough. It's never fun to see your rep drop. Childish? Guilty as charged, but it easy to take downvotes very personal, and especially if they are not motivated.

> Editing: this is certainly a direct way to address the problem, and could be constructive (i.e. "here is a better way to phrase this question"). It might lead to more constructive answers (rather than a snark-fest in the comments), and to upvotes for an otherwise useful question.

It might. It might. not. I would suggest being very careful with this. Do changes that objectively make them better, but be really careful about how you phrase yourself. Do not change the question. (Which I think your above examples are)

> Commenting: it's a milder way to register my disapproval, and I could give suggested edits in a comment and give the original poster the free choice whether to incorporate them.

Probably the best way to go. In the example above, I can honestly say that in my mind I would think "Wtf? Why is he wasting time for me, himself and everybody who is reading this for this little irrelevant detail?" and I would waste some more time in writing an explanation of why I think my version is better.

> Ignoring: life is too short.

Another alternative. Spend some time really thinking what the problem is.